# How to separate 3D computer Vision and 3D Geometry ? What will be subcategories for each of them

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, geometry, linear-algebra

So, I was trying to prepare for an interview but wasn't sure how to split up the topics under 3D CV and 3D geometry or in other words, where should I draw the line between them. For eg, will Epipolar geometry fall under 3D Geometry or 3D CV. Does 3D geometry involve only the Math concepts which is needed for 3D Computer Vision or is there a possible overlap?

Answer (score 1):

3D geometry describes shapes and their properties, in an abstract tridimensional world. It is a branch of mathematics/geometry.

3D computer vision deals with the analysis and understanding of 3D digital images (either voxelated or range). It can also encompass the 3D reconstruction of scenes from 2D images. It is an applied branch of digital image processing (but extending to AI), which uses 3D geometry, but not only.